# Visually representing a list of files

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an array of strings; for example:

> {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"}

I want to display each item on the form in some way where I can alter its style (color, weight, etc.) AFTER the data has been displayed. I do not want to use treeview. My goal is to have it read like a sentence or line-by-line.

Can I change the visual style of specific text in a textBox?

Should I use a loop to create a label for each string? If so how do I position each label to line up properly with other elements on the form?

Comment: I forgot to add that the creation of these visual elements must be called from a separate thread using a delegate.

Comment: You can use a RichTextBox and apply different style for each run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextBlock.

Basic example could be:

YAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="Text1" Margin="10" Foreground="Red">
                    This is a TextBlock control<LineBreak />
                    with multiple lines of text.
    </TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Change Colors" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind-file:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Text1.Foreground = Brushes.Pink;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you could indeed have a textbox for each.

You can change the font and background/foreground of a textbox.  You could also create and position them at runtime to handle how many there are and where they are.

You can create the labels during runtime as well, simply use the same Y axis for both the textbox and label, then jump the Y position a set amount for every "new line".